# What are examples illustrating why quasilinear function is different from monotone function?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

A [quasilinear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasilinear) is a function that is both quasiconvex and quasiconcave. Are there quasilinear functions that are not monotone? Are there monotone functions that are not quasilinear? If so, an example of each would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say $f$ is monotone for a function $f$ defined on one dimension $\mathbb{R}$.
For higher dimension $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\ge 2$), there is a generalization of
the relation between quasilinear and monotone.

See [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYPuw.png), page 122, Exercise 3.46

1) For a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, 
$f$ is quasilinear if and only if $f$ is monotone.

2) For a function of $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ ($n\ge 2$), 
if $f$ is continuous quasilinear, then there is a monotone function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
and $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x) = g(a^T x)$. The converse is also true.

The proof from the solution manual: 
[image]

*References*

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYPuw.png) Boyd and Vandenberghe, "Convex optimization".
http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For completeness, can you prove your claim 2? Also, if possible can you explain why the continuity is needed? Is there a counter-example if continuity does not hold?

Comment: @XuWang  I added the proof from the solution manual.

Comment: Thank you! If I had more points I would give you bounty points but I am currently points-poor. I did not originally accept your answer since it depended on other material and did not contain a proof. Now I think your answer is the most complete. Thank you for your kind answer and update!

Comment: @XuWang You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia’s [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasilinear), a real-valued function $f$ defined on a convex subset $S$ of $\Bbb R$ is quasilinear iff for each $x,y\in S$ and each $\lambda\in [0,1]$ we have 
$$\min\{f(x),f(y)\}\le f(\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y)\le \max\{f(x),f(y)\}.$$
Since $\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y$ is a point of the segment with the endpoints $x$ and $y$ and the minimum and the maximum of a function monotone on a segment are attained at the endpoints of the segment, each monotone function on $S$ is quasilinear on $S$.

On the other hand, each quasilinear function $f$ on $S$ is monotone on $S$. Indeed, suppose to the contrary that $f$ is non-monotone on $S$. It easily follows that there exists points $x<z<y$ of $S$ such that $f(x)<f(z)>f(y)$ or $f(x)>f(z)<f(y)$. Then $z=\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y$ for some $\lambda\in (0,1)$. In the first case $\max\{f(x),f(z)\}<f(\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y)$, so $f$ is non-quasiconvex on $S$. Similarly, in the second case $f$ is non-quasiconcave on $S$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to make sure I understand the large picture, a function is monotone if and only if it is quasilinear, right? If that is true, do you happen to have any intuition for why we would even define quasilinear?

Comment: @XuWang Right, for a convex subset $S$ of $\Bbb R$. I think we could introduce a notion of a quasilinear function because we can define them on convex subsets of (real) vector spaces. From the other hand, we can simply define a  monotone function on a subset of $\Bbb R$ (and, in general, on partially ordered sets), but there is a problem to define an order structure on any vector space. If I remember it right, there is also a topological definition of a monotone function (that maps connected subsets to connected), but it seems that such functions can be very non-quasiconvex even for $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: Thank you, Alex! I am curious about the non-quasiconvex monotone function in R^2. But I suppose I should ask another question for that.

Comment: The point really is that quasiconvex functions require less structure than monotone ones. To define them, you only need the space to a semimodule. In particular, it doesn't have to be ordered. When the space is linearly ordered, quasilinearity coincides with monotonicity.